# .Where() Against Another List

Tags: flutter, dart, where-clause

I have 2 lists. I would like to sort down the users list where it does not contain any users from the members list. I was thinking the where function would work here but Im not sure how to add a list to check against. Is there an optimal solution for something like this?

```
    void _sortMemberList(List<User> users) {
    if (members != null) {
      users = users.where((user) => user.id != /*check against all elements in members*/).toList();
    } 

    emit(state.copyWith(
        members: members,
        nonMembers: users,
      ));
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try:

```
void _sortMemberList(List<User> users) {
  if (members != null) {
    users = users.where((user) => !members.any((member) => member.id == user.id)).toList();
  }

  emit(state.copyWith(
    members: members,
    nonMembers: users,
  ));
}
```

Comment: This is it! I was looking for a solution where I didnt have nested loops and the any function is just what I was looking for.

Comment: Note that this is O(m * n) with respect to the lengths of the lists.  If you can use a `Set` instead of a `List`, it can be done in linear time.